# "doesn't just donate " is the same as "donates not just"

Tags: phrase-meaning

"She doesn't just donate money but is the type of person who visits orphanage"
In that sentence "doesn't just donate but.."has the same meaning as "donates not just but..."? And if the sec phrase is correct "not just but" is the same as "not only but also"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. This question will be easier to answer if you edit it to add more information. Instead of writing partial sentences, please write complete ones.

Comment: I assume you mean to ask _Does it have the same meaning?_  No, it doesn't. "She donates not just money" has to be followed by a statement of something else that she donates - "but also her time", for example. And, yes, this could be expressed as "not only her money but also her time".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KateBunting So "doesn't just donate" simply means "does not donate" ? In that paragraph, "She" is the Queen of particular country and heavily focused on country's welfare.So i don't think that "she does not donate any money but visits to citizens' home " is not appropriate.Sorry for lack of informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*She doesn't just donate money but also visits orphanages* describes two different things that the queen does.

If you begin the sentence with *She donates, not just money but also...*, the second part has to refer to something else that she donates, since that is the main verb in the sentence. That is why I suggested *...but also her time* - you could then go on to say that that time is spent visiting orphanages.